How to balance authorship roles when my contributions are substantial but I am evaluated on last authorship?
I am a senior researcher in computer science, and I am applying for associate professorship positions. The evaluation of my last application was positive overall, except for the concern that I am not listed as the lead author often enough. According to the committee, they interpret the lead author as the last author, which typically signifies the senior supervisor role. In my 45+ publications, I first authored more than 60% of them.
In my role, I supervise multiple students and research staff, but most are not pursuing a PhD and aim to move to industry. Their work often involves small, independent contributions that I combine, significantly enhance, and then write up as full manuscripts where I typically list myself as the first author. This feels appropriate since I do most of the work and writing.
However, this pattern seems to conflict with the committee's expectations. Even if I wanted to credit another as the first author, it would be challenging to pick a single student when the paper is the result of combining several small efforts.
Given this, what is the best way to proceed with manuscripts I already wrote to align better with expectations regarding senior authorship? Should I rethink authorship strategies going forward?

"This feels appropriate since I do most of the work and writing." This is not what a professor should do so, though, right? Rather , they should be delegating significant workto students and podtdocs. It’s unclear to me whether you want to fix the presentation of this mismatch, or the mismatch itself. Can you clarify that?

@MisterMiyagi We cannot force an employee who is not willing to pursue a PhD to conduct more experiments and write manuscripts. If they do it, it would be of course great because less work for me and more publications. At my organization, researchers (and researcher assistants), including myself are not required to publish neither to pursue a PhD but rather complete the tasks of the acquired projects. For master students, it is even more critical because publication is not part of their graduation. Delegating such a task to them is literally "exploitation" unless they aim to stay in academia.

I guess it's probably field dependent, but equating "last author" with "lead author" feels pretty bizarre to me. I mean sure, it can be that the PI comes up with the project, sets a student to work on it, and gets a last authorship as a result, but not all research fits that mould. Sometimes the student first author is the one who came up with the idea and the last author professor is just someone who contributed to it.

Do I guess correctly that these people looking at your CV are not, primarily, from CS, but from a variety of fields? Or, alternatively, from applied CS?

@Yacine It's one thing that you and your students are not required by your current institution to focus on publications as a group. But it does not change that the institutions you are applying to expect you to focus on publications as a group. So my question remains - do you want to fix the appearance of this mismatch, or the mismatch itself?

@Yacine why would "Here new student, read this, understand the work that Alice did before she left the lab, then talk to me about improving it, and finally write it up in a nice paper" exploitative? That would be a very useful learning experience for the student, who'd also get a paper out of it (you could even have them be a co-first author with the departed Alice). It seems like a win-win to me, what am I missing?

@terdon they wrote that "publication is not part of their graduation" and "unless they aim to stay in academia", so seems like OP is supervising non-research-track master students?

@MisterMiyagi   "This is not what a professor should do so, though, right? Rather , they should be delegating significant work to students and podtdocs."  This is one thing I think is wrong with academia today. Successful professors might have many simultaneous PhD and postdocs generating tons of publications. If the professor does not do significant work, except giving the working guidelines to phd students and postdocs, then why is he/she on the list of authors?

In mathematics the list of authors is alphabetical. Generally only people contributing significantly to the content of the paper are in the list of authors.

Since the committee was clear on their concern, where is the difficulty on clarifying to them exactly what you explained here, on how the order of names has come about?


Given this, what is the best way to proceed with manuscripts I already wrote to align better with expectations regarding senior authorship? Should I rethink authorship strategies going forward?

Whenever I mentor younger researchers (towards tenure evaluations, etc.) I emphasise that one should not look at individual detailed metrics and optimize against them specifically, but look at what deeper construct these metrics are supposed to capture. When your committee says that'd expect more papers where you are last author, they, in all likelihood, don't really care so strongly about you having ticked off some boxes in their evaluation form. What they are concerned about is that your publication list demonstrates skill in conducting your own research and integrating smaller contributions of others, but not so much in advising others in their projects. That's a reasonable thing to be concerned about when appointing an associate professor.
In consequence, your approach to deal with this problem should not be "how can I mangle my authorship orders going forward", but "how can I demonstrate these skills in the best way". If you simply start randomly listing your undergrad students and research staff first, your committee is likely to pick up on this and inform you that, no, this was not what they meant. You will need to find ways to (co-)supervise doctoral students for a longer period, so that you can demonstrate your ability to lead the research of others. For example, some people I know at institutions without PhD programs have developed stable relationships with colleagues at other R1 institutions, helped them co-supervise students, and got long-term advisory experience this way.

That's a valid point; however, papers authored by collaborative students at other universities are typically last-authored by their primary supervisors. Currently, I have two PhD students (paid from funding that I acquired) who require a full professor as their main supervisor (as only professors are eligible to officially supervise PhD students), and these professors also expect to be listed as the last authors on their work.

@Yacine Maybe look for some collaborators that are more understandable towards your situation and more willing to share the last authorship? For example, whenever I co-supervise with somebody, my expectation (and what I offer if I'm first-supervisor) is usually that the primary supervisor would be the last author on the first publication, and then the supervisors would do swapsies for last place. I've observed this from more senior academics who used to be my supervisors, so I try to follow their practices in my own work too.

@Yacine My deeper point is to not fuss too much about the specific item "last authorship", and more what that might indicate to an evaluator (lack of experience guiding others). If you can (demonstrably) fix the latter, the lack of the former will become much less of an issue.

Your answer describes the way things SHOULD work, but unfortunately, I've seen some committees be overly literal with this sort of thing. Given that they told OP in so many words that they want to see more last-author papers, it's safest to find a way to get more last-author papers, in my opinion.

@user1149748 well, YMMV. My experience in three different countries has been that committees are usually only nitpicky in cases where they have deeper concerns - if the overall impression is very positive, much can be overlooked. But if it isn't, it's easier to say "checklist item 13.3.c not fulfilled" than "the supervisory experience of the candidate overall does not seem sufficient".

Just to second what xLeitix said, but perhaps put a slightly different spin on it.
You've basically served two roles on the papers you have author - you have devised, directed and had strategic oversight of the project, a role generally associated with last authors, and you have done most of the actual writing and integrating, a role generally associated with first authors. Your committees are tell you they care more devising, directing and oversight of projects than your ability to technically do research and write about it.
I can think of several practical ways forward. You might list yourself last, and then leave a note on the authors list that  authors are listed in alphabetical with the exception of the last author.
You might list yourself first, but mark yourself as corresponding author. In my field marking the corresponding author is to select them as the "senior" author.

Since obtaining my PhD, I have been the corresponding author in all papers I first authored. I think I should emphasize that in my CV.

First author, and corresponding author can mean different things. This too can be field dependent.

@Buffy Indeed, I'm sure it is field specific. In my field the corresponding author is the last author by default, but you can add a special note to say the first author is the corresponding author.
